# Number of clients in the room in socket io v1

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I just started to play with socket.io and try to make something super simple like people connecting to the room.

I expected this to give me the number of clients in the room

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
    socket.on('create or join', function (channel) {
        var numClients = io.sockets.clients(channel).length;
        ...
   }
})
```

But it returns an error: `Object #<Namespace> has no method 'clients'` because something has changed in V.1. After some searches I substituted the callback with another one:

```
    var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[channel];
    var numClients = 0;
    if (typeof clients !== 'undefined'){
        numClients = clients.length;
    }

    p(numClients);   // p is just a wrapper on console.log()
    p(clients);
    socket.join(channel);
    socket.emit('created', channel);
```

But no matter how many times I connect, I get 0 as number of clients:

```
0
undefined
0
[ hSxLuOqrm5bX4UxmAAAA: true ]
0
[ hSxLuOqrm5bX4UxmAAAA: true, '2bjYS0lrUFySPM1OAAAB': true ]
```

What do I do wrong?

**P.S.** here is how to get number of clients in the room:

`var numClients = (typeof clients !== 'undefined') ? Object.keys(clients).length : 0;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This occurs because `clients` array stores sockets not with index keys, but with string keys (like an object).

To demonstrate this take a look at the following code:

```
var clients = [];
clients.somekey1 = true;
clients.somekey2 = true;

console.log(clients.length);
console.log(clients);
```

Here is the output:

```
0
[ somekey1: true, somekey2: true ]
```

The actual length of this array is `0` despite having properties in it. So you should consider `clients` array as an object, and thus counting the number of clients in this "object" may be performed with the following line of code:

```
var numClients = Object.keys(clients).length;
```

[From the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> The **`Object.keys()`** method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

and this is exactly what we need.

Comment: This works well, but is the number of opened sessions. If a client have 3 browsers tabs, the numClients will be 3... How to get the number real of users connected in a room?